# Modify .bashrc variable from a loop from shell

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

So I created this loop in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export test_var1=TRUE
for (( a=0;a<1;a )); do
if [[ $test_var1 == "TRUE" ]]; then
        sleep 1
        echo "teststuff happening! test_var1=${test_var1}"
        sleep 10
fi
done &
```

And it has the expected effect, the `echo "teststuff...` is getting echoed every 11 seconds on my terminal:

```
me@yes:~$ teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
```

But when I try to change the variable, it doesn't take effect:

```
me@yes:~$ teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
test_var1=no
me@yes:~$ teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
export test_var1=no
me@yes:~$ teststuff happening! test_var1=TRUE
```

How do I export a variable from my shell such that it also changes on the loop that's running from `~/.bashrc`?

My practical use for this was to see my battery life on the terminal (even when on TTY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for … do … done &` in your code runs in the background because of `&`. Shell code that runs in the background runs in a subshell. Such subshell inherits variables ([even unexported ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157957/108618)) but it inherits them as copies, not references. So `test_var1` in your `for` loop is a variable distinct from `test_var1` in your main shell. The only connection is the variable in the loop was initiated with the value of the variable in the main shell current at the moment the subshell was created. After that each variable is on its own and does not affect the other.

That's why when you change `test_var1` in the main shell, the subshell does not reflect it.

You don't want to run the loop in the foreground (without `&`). If you do this then a new shell that sources `.bashrc` will stuck in the loop and never get to the point when it gives you the prompt. And if you manage to break the loop and get the prompt anyway then the loop will be no more.

In Bash you cannot "export a variable from your shell such that it also changes on the loop" that runs in the background. Few ideas:

1. Instead of the variable use a regular file. Two shells can operate on the same file. You can pass information as the content of the file. Here, since you need exactly one bit of information (on/off), you can pass it as mere existence of the file. Useful start: `myfile="$(mktemp)"` run in the main shell, so it and a subshell started later can use the variable (actually two identical and constant variables) to locate the file.
2. In the subshell set `trap`s, so after receiving `SIGUSR1` the subshell changes its own `test_var1` one way, and after receiving `SIGUSR2` it changes the variable the other way. The main shell should memorize the PID of the subshell (`bckgrndPID=$!`) and you will `kill -s USR1 "$bckgrndPID"` etc. when you want to change the state. It will be cumbersome to type these `kill` commands, so you will probably want to define two functions like `on` and `off`.
3. And since you would need to use functions, you can simplify things by taking yet another approach: let `on` be a function that starts the background process if not already started; let `off` terminate it. Quite straightforward:

   ```sh
   on () {
     [ "$bckgrndPID" ] && return 0
     while :; do
       echo "teststuff happening!"
       sleep 10
     done &
     bckgrndPID=$!
   }

   off () {
     [ "$bckgrndPID" ] && kill "$bckgrndPID"
     unset bckgrndPID
   }
   ```
4. Regarding your plans:

   > My practical use for this was to see my battery life on the terminal (even when on TTY).

   Use `tmux` and its status line ([search for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=tmux%20battery%20in%20status)).

Comment: Thank you! Nr. 1 seems the best for my use case, since in that way I can disable and re-enable it without having to source `.bashrc` again.